# Invoking make install on a subdirectory before make all

Tags: cmake, makefile

I am working on migrating a C++ project whose configuration currently is a combination of cmake (CMakeLists.txt) and Make (GNUmakefile), to using only cmake. The way it's currently set is:

```
myproject
|  CMakeLists.txt (add_subdirectory(src))
|  src/
|    apps/
|      myapp/
|        [myapp source files]
|        GNUmakefile
|      ...
|    libs/
|      mylib/
|        [mylib source files]
|        GNUmakefile
|      ...
|    common/
|      CMakeLists.txt (add_subdirectory(dir1, dir2, dir3...))
|      ...
|  include/
```

There *are* more apps and libs outside of myapp and mylib, but they all build and link in similar ways, so if I have one, I can get all.

The way the project builds right now, there is a script that essentially has 4 lines:

```
cmake path/to/myproject    // with the necessary flags and variables passed
make all DESTDIR=$INSTALL_DIR install
cd src/libs ; make all
cd src/apps ; make all
```

This works because `common`, which has no dependencies, builds and installs first (`include` also gets installed here), then `libs` - which depends on `common` - builds, and then `apps` - which depends on both `libs` and `common` - builds.

My problem is, if I replace the `GNUmakefile`s in `libs` and `apps`, I don't know how to change the commands I run in the build script so that cmake and make are interwoven like so:

1. *cmake* configures `common`
2. *make* compiles & installs all the *cmake* targets from `common` (let's say those are libcommon.so and libcommonutils.so)
3. *cmake* configures `libs`
4. *make* compiles & installs all the *cmake* targets from `libs` (which uses the libraries from `common` to produce `mylib.a`)
5. *cmake* configures `apps`
6. *make* compiles &  installs all the *cmake* targets from `apps` (which uses `mylib.a` and the `common` shared libraries)

Installing `include` will also have to happen at some point, early on, since `common` depends on the header files inside it.

An alternative solution might also work, of course, but this (interweaving cmake and make calls) is the only one I could think of.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:c] or [tag:c++], unless you can prove that they are relevant tags, remove them and you will get better help and sooner. I don't remove them because there might be something I am missing.

Comment: Are the `GNUMakefiles` too extensive? Have you tried to convert their funcionality into `CMakeLists.txt`'s?

Comment: Can you please post 1. How many "*apps*" are build with the `GNUMakefile` at the `apps` directory. 2. How is their code organized. 3. The same for `libs`.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question? There is no good reason.

Comment: @iharob, not sure. Probably not relevant. Figured more tags is better because of a more complete description... Also, I do have CMakeLists to serve as replacements for the GNUmakefiles. That part I can and have done. I'll update my original post with details about the apps and libs, but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: if it already properly works, why spend the time and effort changing it?

Comment: Because the plan is for the GNUmakefile setup to go away sometime in the near future, and I have some extra time on my hands now. I'd rather figure out the shift now.

Comment: @iharob: I don't think the question is general enough to be a good question. I would like to see more a more abstract question. This could be a reason to downvote.

Comment: @usr1234567 It could be, but it shouldn't be in my opinion. This could be useful for many users and the structure of the question is good, the content is sufficient to try and answer so at least don't vote on it at all. But of course, that's an opinion. I just wanted to know what were the reasons of the downvoter, because apparently some users just downvote for no reason.

Comment: Is **configuration** of `libs` actually depends from `common` being configured/built/installed? If not, just use [ExternalProject_add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) for `common` and make all targets in `libs` dependent from that external target. This effectively garantees that `common` will be *installed* before *building* `libs`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, the configuration itself doesn't depend on `common`, it's only a compile-time dependency. And even then, the dependency is more on the headers in `include` (whose implementation is in `common`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ExternalProject_add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) for `common`, `libs` and `apps`.

**src/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
ExternalProject_add(common
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/common
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/common
    # Forward CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to external project.
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)

ExternalProject_add(libs
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs
    # Disable *install* step
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_add(apps
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/apps
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/apps
    # Disable *install* step
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

# Adjust dependencies between components
add_dependencies(libs common)
add_dependencies(apps libs common)
```

Usage of this script(out-of-source build; in-source build is also supported)

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install-dir> <source-dir>
make
```

is equvalent to the following sequence of commands:

```
mkdir src/common && cd src/common \
    && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install-dir> <source-dir>/src/common && make install
mkdir src/libs && cd src/libs && cmake <source-dir>/src/libs && make all
mkdir src/apps && cd src/apps && cmake <source-dir>/src/apps && make all
```

Processing of `include` is not implemented, but you may do that in similar way.